# Install gdal in CentOS without Root

Tags: python, linux, centos

I have been struggling to get python setup to do some image processing, so I really need the http://www.gdal.org/ GDAL libraries installed on CentOS 6.5. I want to install the package in a local folder (maybe `/workspace/GDAL`) without root access. When I try to build from source, it seems CentOS is missing a bunch of libraries.

Please, web-wizards and sysadmin gurus, can you point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I will be using it for opening HDF4, HDF4-EOS files, and have a local installation of the HDF4/HDF5 libraries (say `/workspace/HDF`). If I can install a binary without root, is there a way to point GDAL to these libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anaconda distribution it has precompiled version of gdal

https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

And you dont have to compile anything, installs in home directory, doesn't require root access

Comment: I dont know much about gdal/hdf5 but there is hdf5 library available via conda, conda install hdf5, maybe that help

Comment: @idwalker thank you, but `conda install hdf4` did not work, and I need both HDF4/HDF5.

Comment: binstar.org has packages for anaconda, here might work (its 64bit) conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/mutirri hdf4

Comment: I am sorry i dont know much about gdal stuff, If you can verify the python you are using is from anaconda. typing which python should give ~/anaconda/bin/python like so. other than that ... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66812/processing-modis-hdf-files-with-gdal

Comment: I figured out that the best conda package is one by [Jose](https://conda.binstar.org/jgomezdans): `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/jgomezdans gdal=1.11.0` Thank you!